# Istio Delegate Virtual Service

Tags: istio

I am attempting to do the following in Istio:

1. Match `api.example.com/<service>/...`.
2. Rewrite the matched URL portion to `/` (e.g., `/<service>/...` to `/...`).
3. [Delegate](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Delegate) to an existing Virtual Service for `<service>`.

The existing Virtual Services support host `<service>.example.com`, which needs to be preserved. I need to support the single host in addition to the dedicated hosts.

For example, I would expect the following to route both `api.example.com/svcA/api/foo/bar` and `svcA.example.com/api/foo/bar` to destination `svcA.nsB.svc.cluster.local`.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
  namespace: nsA
spec:
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - nsA/api.example.com
    - nsB/svcA.example.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: single-hostname
  namespace: nsA
spec:
  gateways:
  - nsA/gateway
  hosts:
  - api.example.com
  http:
  - delegate:
      name: svcA
      namespace: nsB
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /svcA/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: svcA
  namespace: nsB
spec:
  gateways:
  - nsA/gateway
  hosts:
  - svcA.example.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/foo/bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: svcA.nsB.svc.cluster.local
```

`svcA.example.com/api/foo/bar` works as expected, but Istio returns `404 NR route_not_found` for `api.example.com/svcA/api/foo/bar`, and I'm not sure why exactly. Any guidance here is appreciated.